# How to load yaml files instad of json file in ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-translate

- We are converting Angular 1.x to angular
- In version 1 we have been using yaml files for localization
- In angular latest verison we have a plugin called **ngx-translate** for
  this multi lingual localization
- But it loads **json** file on default for loading values
- **How to make load yaml files on default in ngx-translate , is there
  any way to do this?**

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late but this question has some views. I didn't find a straightforward solution by googling so I publish mine.

I did it for Angular 15

So, if someone looking for a solution you can do something like this:

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml
import { parse } from 'yaml';

...

class TranslateYamlHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public path: string = '/assets/i18n/'
  ) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.path}${lang}.yaml`, { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(map((data) => parse(data)));
  }
}

...

@NgModule({
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateYamlHttpLoader(http),
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Create translation file src/assets/i18n/en.yaml

```
hello: Hello Angular
validation:
  required: Field is required
```

Now you can use ngx-translate as usual:

```
<button>
  {{ 'hello' | translate }}
</button>

<div>
  {{ 'validation.required' | translate }}
</div>
```

This is similar to https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/projects/ngx-translate/http-loader/src/lib/http-loader.ts

I just added yaml parsing